# Validate quantities with whole numbers

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to get my input fields to only accept whole numbers and wrote some java to help validate, but every time I click on the next input to insert a value, it sends off my alert.  Am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cartAmount, subtotal, pstAmount, pstTax, gstTax, taxAmount, shipCharge, afterTax; 

    function validate() {
        //Whole Numbers with Regexp
            var rx = new RegExp(/\d+/);

            if(document.getElementsByClassName("inputValue").value != rx || document.getElementsByClassName("inputValue").value == "") {
                alert("Please use only whole quantities.");
                return false;
            }
    }
    function sumCart() {

        //Adding Cart Values
            cartAmount = (document.frmMain.item1.value * 3.99) + (document.frmMain.item2.value * 5.99); 

        //Finding Subtotals
            document.frmMain.subtotalAmt.value = Math.round(cartAmount*100)/100;
            subtotal = document.frmMain.subtotalAmt.value;

        //Finding Taxes
            pstTax = document.frmMain.taxAmount.value;
            gstTax = .05;

            pstAmount = Math.round((subtotal * pstTax)*100)/100;
            gstAmount = Math.round((subtotal * gstTax)*100)/100;

            taxAmount = parseFloat(pstAmount,10) + parseFloat(gstAmount,10);

            document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax in dollars is $" + Math.round(taxAmount * 100)/100;

        //Finding Total
            shipCharge = 0;
            afterTax = parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(taxAmount) + parseFloat(shipCharge);
            document.frmMain.totalAmt.value = Math.round(afterTax*100)/100;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the bounty or offer of something in return for us doing your work everyday?

Comment: it's not every day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this validation function:

```
function validate() {
    //Whole Numbers with Regexp
    var rx = new RegExp(/^\d+$/);
    inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputValue");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i].value;
        if (!rx.test(input)) {
           alert("Please use only whole quantities.");
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Your code had several problems:

1. The regexp `/\d+/` just checks whether the value has any digits in it, it doesn't check that it *only* has digits. You need to anchor to the beginning and end with `^` and `$` to check the entire value.
2. You were using `value != rx`, which doesn't perform regexp testing. You have to use `rx.test()`.
3. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. You need to loop over them to get the values.

Comment: thank you very much.  I have used ElementsByClassName due to the fact I have multiple inputs that need to be checked if the value of it is a whole number.

Comment: I understand why you used that. It seems like checking the Javascript console for errors would have shown you that you were using it incorrectly.